# Problem finding link in text using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I'm doing a site parsing and moved to the level of json formation. I have links in the text that I thought it would be nice to keep as well. To do this, I use a regular expression, but it does not work quite correctly.

Text:

```
  \r\n<li><a href="http://chechnya.gov.ru/wp-content/uploads/documents/226-8.pdf">Regulations documents</a></li>\r\n</ul>\r\n'
```

Regex:

```
link = re.findall("(?P<url>https?://\S+)", str(region))
print(link)
```

Result find:

```
['http://chechnya.gov.ru/wp-content/uploads/documents/226-8.pdf">Regulations']
```

How can I change the regular expression to fix it a little and remove the extra word at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's always in a href attribute in the format you showed using `"` or `'` you could use:

```
region = "  \r\n<li><a href=\'http://chechnya.gov.ru/wp-content/uploads/documents/226-8.pdf\'>Regulations documents</a></li>\r\n</ul>\r\n'"
link = re.findall("https?://[^\"']*", region)
print(link)
> ['http://chechnya.gov.ru/wp-content/uploads/documents/226-8.pdf']
```

Which matches any substring starting with `https://` or `http://` and everything afterwards until the first `"` or `'` character. Should work since `"` and `'` is escaped in URLs and therefore can not occur in the middle of the url.

Generally using regex to parse HTML yourself is a bad idea and makes life harder for you than it needs to be. Just use a parser and properly access the attributes, e.g. like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(region, "lxml")
link = soup.find('li').find('a')['href']  # finds the first <a> in the first <li> and returns the value of the attribute 'href'
print(link)
> http://chechnya.gov.ru/wp-content/uploads/documents/226-8.pdf
```

Or if you have a document with many of those `<li>` tags:

```
for li in soup.findAll('li'):
    link = li.find('a')['href']
    print(link)
```